# Высоконагруженные операции в Wordpress?

Tags: php

Мне необходимо через Wordpress крон запускать задачу, что предполагает итерацию по базе данных. Сложность O(n) от количества записей в базе данных. Если я просто сделаю обычный запуск, я не "подвешу" сайт. Как мне сделать это в отдельном потоке, что-ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Крон и работает в отдельном процессе("потоке")

Не подвесишь, если не включишь блокировку таблиц - апдейть в транзакциях небольшими порциями